# When I npm run dev I get an error: cannot find module "postcss/lib/parser"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, next.js

I'm using Next js and whenever I run the script "npm run dev" I get this error, which confuses me, because when I checked the "lib" folder thats within the postcss folder, I found parser.js file is in there, so why doesnt node find the module.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\jaydev\Documents\create-test\test-project\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser'
    at createEsmNotFoundErr (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:952:15)
    at finalizeEsmResolution (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:945:15)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:473:14)
    at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:513:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:911:27)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.552 (C:\Users\jaydev\Documents\create-test\test-project\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\postcss-scss\scss-syntax.js:1:11590)
    at __nccwpck_require__ (C:\Users\jaydev\Documents\create-test\test-project\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\postcss-scss\scss-syntax.js:1:11735)    
    at Object.270 (C:\Users\jaydev\Documents\create-test\test-project\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\postcss-scss\scss-syntax.js:1:400)
    at __nccwpck_require__ (C:\Users\jaydev\Documents\create-test\test-project\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\postcss-scss\scss-syntax.js:1:11735)    
    at Object.327 (C:\Users\jaydev\Documents\create-test\test-project\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\postcss-scss\scss-syntax.js:1:260)
    at __nccwpck_require__ (C:\Users\jaydev\Documents\create-test\test-project\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\postcss-scss\scss-syntax.js:1:11735)    
    at Object.845 (C:\Users\jaydev\Documents\create-test\test-project\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\postcss-scss\scss-syntax.js:1:3733)
    at __nccwpck_require__ (C:\Users\jaydev\Documents\create-test\test-project\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\postcss-scss\scss-syntax.js:1:11735) {  
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\jaydev\\Documents\\create-test\\test-project\\node_modules\\postcss\\package.json'
}
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\jaydev\Documents\create-test\test-project
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c next dev

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jaydev\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-21T05_42_49_737Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to install this module also

```
npm install @types/parse
```

for detailed information please check here :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't fix the problem